# Move specific set of lines from a Flat File into another

Tags: c#, header-files

I am trying to dump the contents of a file into another file using c#. Not the entire content but only specific set of lines. I read the file into an array.

Now what I want to do is I want to remove certain number of lines, say from a total of 50 lines of file, first 10 lines and bottom 20 lines are to be excluded.

My code looks like

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\manoj\File.txt");
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\manoj\sample.txt");
for (i = 10; i <= 30; i++)
   {
       foreach(string line in lines)
       {
           file.writeline(line[i]);
       }
   }
```

**Index is out of bound for the array** is the error that I am getting.

Can someone please advise me?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing, for each line of the file, to each char from the 10th to the 30th.
At the first line containing less than 30 char, the program raise the error you get

Comment: okay.... Got it.. So if I want to move it per line, then what should I use there ??

Comment: thest string length before accessing i-th char
`if (i < line.length)
file.writeline(line[i]);`

Comment: if you want to retrieve lines from 10 to 30, don't use foreach:

`for (int i = 10; i < 30 && i < lines.Length; i++)
 file.writeline(lines[i]);.`

Answer (score 0):

You should not be nesting the loop that counts to 30 with the loop that iterates over the lines in your file.  Try this

```
var total_lines = lines.Count;
var linecount = 0;
foreach(string line in lines) {   
    linecount ++;
    if (linecount >= 10 || linecount <= total_lines - 20) {
        file.writeline(line);
    }
}
```

This uses the `linecount` variable to count your lines, and then selectively outputs based on the value of that variable.